# Show user's Selected Image when user accesses photos

Tags: swift, swiftui, uiimagepickercontroller, ios14, phpickerviewcontroller

I tried to show only photo that I selected before, but it won't work and show all photos. How do I solve this issue? I tried to use permission to limited access but it end up showing all of the photos - not just the photo I selected.

Photos show image

[image]

Permission selected image

[image]

This is my `View`'s code:

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var isPickerShowing = false
    @State var selectedImage: UIImage?
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            
            if selectedImage != nil {
                Image(uiImage: selectedImage!).resizable().frame(width: 200, height: 200)
            }
            
            Button {
                checkPermission()
            } label: {
                Text("select Photo")
            }
        }
        .sheet(isPresented: $isPickerShowing, onDismiss: nil) {
            //Image Picker
            ImagePicker(selectedImage: $selectedImage, isPickerShowing: $isPickerShowing)
        }
        
    }
    
    func checkPermission() {
        
       let photoAuthorizationStatus = PHPhotoLibrary.authorizationStatus()
       switch photoAuthorizationStatus {
       case .authorized:
           print("Access is granted by user")
           isPickerShowing = true
       case .notDetermined:
           PHPhotoLibrary.requestAuthorization({
               (newStatus) in
               print("status is \(newStatus)")
               if newStatus ==  PHAuthorizationStatus.authorized {
                   /* do stuff here */
                   isPickerShowing = true
               }
           })
           print("It is not determined until now")
       case .restricted:
           // same same
           print("User do not have access to photo album.")
       case .denied:
           // same same
           print("User has denied the permission.")
       case .limited:
           print("User Limited Show Photo.")
       @unknown default:
           print("User Unknow")
       }
        
   }
    
}
```

here my ImagePicker:

```swift
struct ImagePicker: UIViewControllerRepresentable {
    
    @Binding var selectedImage: UIImage?
    @Binding var isPickerShowing: Bool
    
    func makeUIViewController(context: Context) -> some UIViewController {
        
        let imagePicker = UIImagePickerController()
        imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
        imagePicker.delegate = context.coordinator
        return imagePicker
        
    }
    
    func updateUIViewController(_ uiViewController: UIViewControllerType, context: Context) {}
    
    func makeCoordinator() -> Coordinator {
        return Coordinator(self)
    }
    
}

class Coordinator: NSObject, UIImagePickerControllerDelegate, UINavigationControllerDelegate {
    
    var parent: ImagePicker
    
    init(_ picker: ImagePicker) {
        self.parent = picker
    }
    
    func imagePickerController(_ picker: UIImagePickerController, didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo info: [UIImagePickerController.InfoKey : Any]) {
        
        if let image = info[UIImagePickerController.InfoKey.originalImage] as? UIImage {
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self.parent.selectedImage = image
            }
        }
        self.parent.isPickerShowing = false
        
    }
    
    func imagePickerControllerDidCancel(_ picker: UIImagePickerController) {
        self.parent.isPickerShowing = false
    }
    
}
```

I aim to only show the selected image.

Comment: Can you include a [mre]? There's a lot here that won't compile

Comment: already edited code